# Grouping into least number of betslips

Tags: algorithm

This is a practical problem in betting (for placing betslip).

For example, in trifecta, originally I intend to place 6 betslips, each with unit bet amount of $10. Hence, the total bet amount will be $60=6×$10 originally.

The task is to group these individual betslips because unit bet in grouped betslips is reduced to costs $5 each, instead of $10. I am trying to reduce the total bet amount.

In the example picture below, the blue betslips in method 1 or 2 are the grouped betslips. Hence the total bet amount will be 2×$5+$10+2×$5+$10=$40.

[image: example]

If there are much more betslips (n betslips), what is the best algorithm to group all betslips?

Seemingly there can be many ways to group them, like the above example

Answer (score 1):

Make a graph where the nodes correspond to betslips and the edges represent pairs of betslips that can be grouped. Run the Blossom algorithm (I know [NetworkX](https://networkx.org/) has [an implementation](https://networkx.org/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.matching.max_weight_matching.html)) to find a maximum matching in this non-bipartite graph and group accordingly.